# Span adding unexpected height to sibling

Tags: css, less

I am having trouble adding a validation indicator to my input fields in my creditcards form.

For some reason, having the span adds height to the `span.input-group-addon`, resulting in empty space below the input

```
<template name="checkoutForm">
```

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="bs-example bs-example-form">

        <div class="no-margin">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon input-group-sm"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkoutCardNumber" placeholder="Card Number">
              <span class="validity"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And LESS

```
@import '../../../../stylesheets/variables.import.less';
@import '../../../../stylesheets/mixins.import.less';


.checkout-form {
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: auto;

  .no-margin {
    .form-group {
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0px;
    }
  }

  .validity {
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -27px;
    left: 215px;
    z-index: 1000;
    .valid {
      color: @brand-primary;
    }
    .invalid {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: you code isn't showing enough to explain your question.

Comment: updated post with more code

Comment: thanks for the update, but please post CSS rather than LESS

Comment: did you try removing the line feed between input and span like this? ->  `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkoutCardNumber" placeholder="Card Number"><span class="validity"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting rid of the extra whitespace is removing the line feeds or spaces between elements

You can change

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkoutCardNumber" placeholder="Card Number">
<span class="validity"></span>
```

to

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkoutCardNumber" placeholder="Card Number"><span class="validity"></span>
```

Another way is to set the parent element class' `font-size` attribute to zero.

So try adding

```
font-size:0;
white-space:nowrap;
```

to `input-group` class. Or change the markup as follows

```
<div class="input-group" style="font-size:0;white-space:nowrap;">
```

But then you have to specify the `font-size` attribute in `validity` class in order to display the text within.

Another way is to add

```
float:left;
```

to `validity` class. You'll probably have to add that to input's class too.

**EDIT**

It appears that the problem has nothing to do with the issues above.

Simply remove `<span class="validity"></span>` outside of `<div class="input-group">` as follows and see if that works

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon input-group-sm"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkoutCardNumber" placeholder="Card Number">
</div>
<span class="validity"></span>
```

**EDIT 2**

Change `validity` class as follows

```
 .validity {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 215px;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
```

and use the markup below (your original)

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon input-group-sm"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkoutCardNumber" placeholder="Card Number">
  <span class="validity"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/PJKccNsBdS does that define your problem? edit: or this http://www.bootply.com/ipS239sXu1

Comment: The second one is exactly the problem im having

Comment: That looks better, but now the height is increased on the `class="col-xs-12"` element

Comment: Tried to use Divs instead but didn't work. I appreciate the help very much btw.

Comment: i have updated the answer again, just let me know if that works out for you.

Comment: The absolute positioning messes up scrolling, and the icon now gets higher again

Comment: i see.. i can't see the icon on bootply, so i can't see the exact output. my bootstrap library won't recognize `fa-credit-card` class, but `icon-credit-cart` works and there's no problem with it's layout. wish i could help but can't progress any further unless you provide me a demo page..